# 3-connected multigraph and parallel edge

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

In Diestel book, 5th edition, page 62, he says in the footnote "Recall also that 3-connected multigraphs cannot have multiple edges". Also, in the proof for Lemma 3.2.1, he uses "the fact" that "$G\,\dot{-}\,e$ graph has no parallel edges."

Isn't it obviously false? I can start with any 3-connected graph and start adding arbitrary edges and parallel edges and it will still remain 3-connected. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, the problem is cleared up when we see the part of the context that you didn't tell us about. Immediately before [the sentence that you quote](https://books.google.de/books?id=zIxRDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22Recall%20also%20that%203-connected%20multigraphs%20cannot%20have%20multiple%20edges%22&source=bl&ots=SMlrWsJwQ9&sig=_U-bBqp25IaUzXAkkSf8AVrPbsI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKsYSU88HcAhWEIJoKHe0KDw8Q6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Recall%20also%20that%203-connected%20multigraphs%20cannot%20have%20multiple%20edges%22&f=false), in that same footnote, he suggests to “See Chapter $1.10$ for the formal definition of suppressing vertices in a multigraph”. Chapter $1.10$ contains [the following explanation](https://books.google.de/books?id=zIxRDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA62&ots=SMlrWsJwQ9&dq=%22Recall%20also%20that%203-connected%20multigraphs%20cannot%20have%20multiple%20edges%22&hl=de&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> A few differences, however, should be pointed out. [...] The ends of loops and parallel edges in a multigraph $G$ are considered as separating that edge from the rest of $G$. [...] Thus, a multigraph with a loop is never $2$-connected, and any $3$-connected multigraph is in fact a graph.

Comment: I'm having some trouble seeing why one would consider an edge to be separated from the rest of the graph by removing its endpoints _if but only if_ there's another edge in parallel to it. Why would that not apply to _all_ edges (meaning that _no_ nontrivial graph could be 3-connected)? [Unfortunately the book doesn't really explain this, so we're left to guess].

Comment: @HenningMakholm: The discussion in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370775) seems relevant to that question.

Comment: I do not understand the separating concept in multigraphs at all. How can the vertex $v$ which is the ends of a loop edge $e$ separate it from $G$? If we remove $v$ from the graph to get $G\setminus \{v\}$, then the edge $e$ is also removed, so how can $v$ separate $e$? Similarly, I do not understand the parallel edge separating concept.