# Diestel multigraph separation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, multigraphs

Hi am reading Diestel graph theory. In the 5th edition, in Chapter 1.10, it says:

> The ends of loops and parallel edges in a multigraph G are considered as
> separating that edge from the rest of G. The vertex v of a loop e, there-
> fore, is a cutvertex unless ({v}, {e}) is a component of G, and ({v}, {e})
> is a ‘block’ in the sense of Chapter 3.1. Thus, a multigraph with a loop
> is never 2-connected, and any 3-connected multigraph is in fact a graph.

I don't understand what this means, or why we are defining separation like this. Please can someone explain?

I looked at the answer here:
[Definition of 2-connectedness in multigraphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370775/definition-of-2-connectedness-in-multigraphs)
which answers my first question, except idk what they mean: is it "add a vertex on each edge for ALL sets of parallel edges"? or "add a vertex on all edges parallel to a given edge (which itself doesn't get a vertex)?"

Also I totally don't see the benefit of defining things like this, what are the advantages?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts of this: defining connectivity in the presence of loops, and defining it in the presence of parallel edges.

---

Diestel spends most of this paragraph talking about what happens for loops: we just consider any vertex with a loop to be a cut vertex, *except* when that vertex is in a connected component by itself, and has exactly one loop. This is a weird exception, but it will be justified.

I think Diestel is on firm ground here. Several things about vertex connectivity go wrong unless you do *something* about loops. For example, we would like it to be the case that when you subdivide an edge in a $2$-connected graph (replacing it by a path of length $k$ whose internal vertices are completely new to the graph; informally, "drawing some dots" on the edge) the new graph is also $2$-connected. This is not true if you subdivide a loop. Also, we would like it to be the case that a plane graph is $2$-connected if and only if its dual is $2$-connected. This is also false if we're not careful about loops.

Some alternatives are:

- West's *Introduction to graph theory* just assumes that graphs have no loops in the chapter on connectivity.
- Bondy and Murty's *Graph theory* defines a cut vertex in the usual way, but defines a *separating vertex* to be a vertex $v$ such that $G$ is the union of two graphs, each with at least one edge, that only have vertex $v$ (and no edges) in common. Then a vertex with a loop and at least one more edge is a separating vertex, but not a cut vertex.

I think Bondy and Murty's approach is the most helpful for understanding what is going on here: the notion of a separating vertex is one that generalizes to everything Diestel wants to say about loops. In fact, it also explains what Diestel thinks about isolated vertices: they are cut vertices if they have $0$ loops or $1$ loop, but not if they have $2$ or more loops. That is exactly when Bondy and Murty define the isolated vertex to be a separating vertex.

---

Diestel also seems to claim that in any multigraph $G$ where two vertices $u$ and $v$ are connected by two or more parallel edges, the set $\{u,v\}$ is to be considered a vertex cut, even if $G- \{u,v\}$ (which gets rid of any number of parallel edges) is still connected.

Here, I cannot see why Diestel does so, and no other sources seem to be doing anything similar. (For the most part, in other textbooks, the connectivity of a multigraph with parallel edges is treated in the same way as the connectivity of the underlying simple graph.)

There are some results about $3$-connected planar graphs as well: their plane embeddings are combinatorially unique, and their dual graphs are simple. As far as I can tell, these continue to hold for multigraphs with some parallel edges in which the underlying graph is $3$-connected, and there is no need for Diestel's definition.